# import cv2 error in amazon AWS

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-ec2

[import cv2 module to amazon AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz2sL.jpg)

Hi guys,

I have no problem in import cv2 module on my local computer. But I got this error when running the codes in AWS. Thank you very much for help and guide.

Comment: See the error in the picture please, just click the title "import cv2 module to amazon AWS". Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Amazon AMI doesn’t have a yum repo for the libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0. So, you need to install other distro packages. Simply install the following packages, and you'd be fine

```
sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/hicolor-icon-theme-0.11-1.1.el6.noarch.rpm

$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-1.30.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.x86_64.rpm

$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

[Source](https://ubunifu.co/python/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-amazon-linux-ami-2017-03-1)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, based on your comments, I was able to refine the search keywords and found a better solution for windows users. Here is the solution link: https://github.com/udacity/sdc-issue-reports/issues/768

Answer (score 0):

In my case, check your opencv version. My opencv version was downgraded by some packages.

When I update opencv again to "3.4.2". It works.